# repository pattern in laravel doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

```
App::bind('App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository',
                   function( $app, array $parameters)
{
    return new App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository($parameters[0]);
} );

Route::get('/test/{id}', 'testController@getme');



<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository;
class test extends Controller
{
    //
    protected $language;
    public function __construct(languageRepository $rep){
        $this->language = $rep;
    }


    public function getme(){
        $this->language->getMe();
    }
}
```

When user accesses the route /test/5 for example, it goes to test Controller. what I'd like to do is that it should automatically pass my route parameter to App:bind function and automatically create languageRepository class with the constructor value passed as my route paramter. what happens is the code actually tells me $parameters[0] is undefined offset. why is that? I've tried App::make but then how do I pass the parameter from route to App::make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the container's request instance, for query parameters:

```
App::bind('App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository',function($app)
{
    $request = $app['request'];

    $parameters = $request->all();

    return new App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository($parameters[0]);
});
```

You can accomplish this using the container's request instance, for a route parameter:

```
App::bind('App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository',function($app)
{
    $request = $app['request'];

    $segment = $request->segment(1);

    return new App\Http\Repositories\languageRepository($segment);
});
```

Comment: It says undefined offset 0

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili. Updated the answer, the reason for the undefined offset is because you don't have any query parameters. Instead use `->segment($theindexforyourparameter)`

Comment: Do you think my requirements and your solution are good practice?

Comment: I think it depends on the context of your controller methods and what each of them would need to accomplish. If the parameter you are looking for is always in a fixed place (the same place for all methods), this approach alleviates some mechanical concerns such as defining an argument for each controller method. I might consider taking this approach if this were the case.